# The group policy "Disable machine account password changes" - what does this mean?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, group-policy

I am setting up a test environment on Amazon Web Services comprising of 2 web servers, 1 database server and 1 domain controller. All of them are Windows Server 2012 and joined to the domain. 
Occasionally, the member servers have been randomly throwing the error "the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed" randomly. I am able to fix this problem by doing a local login on the offending computer and then executing the PowerShell command "Reset-ComputerMachinePassword" . No problem after that.

However, I am wondering if the root cause of the problem is because the policy "Disable machine account password changes" is enabled. Should I disable this policy and what would be the consequences if I were to disable this policy?

Please note the policy "Maximum machine account password age" has a value 30 days.

thanks,
SDG

Comment: I will give ServerFault a try.